# How to fill a set of columns values with values of another set of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a `dataframe` with two column sections `Pn` and `En`:

```
df_original = pd.DataFrame({
    'P1':['','',1,''],
    'P2':[4,2,'',3],
    'P3':[48,20,10,''],
    'P4':['',320,160,264],
    'E1':['','',1,3],
    'E2':[4,2,10,264],
    'E3':[48,20,'',528],
    'E4':['','','',792],
    'E5':['','','','']
})
```

|  | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | E1 | E2 | E3 | E4 | E5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 4 | 48 |  |  | 4 | 48 |  |  |
| 1 |  | 2 | 20 | 320 |  | 2 | 20 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 |  | 10 | 160 | 1 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | 3 |  | 264 | 3 | 264 | 528 | 792 |  |

I try to use the `Pn` section as overlay for the `En` section to fill up its empty values with following conditions:

- Values that already exist in the `En` section must not be taken over from the `Pn` section.
- Ideally, values gaps in the `En` section are closed (i.e. index row 2), whereby leading blank values in `E1`, if not filled by a value from `P1`, must not be indented to the left. (In case of doubt, also without moving any values to the left, may it is easier.)

So in result it should end up in something like:

|  | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | E1 | E2 | E3 | E4 | E5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 4 | 48 |  |  | 4 | 48 |  |  |
| 1 |  | 2 | 20 | 320 |  | 2 | 20 | 320 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  | 10 | 160 | 1 | 10 | 160 |  |  |
| 3 |  | 3 |  | 264 | 3 | 264 | 528 | 792 |  |

My first thought was to transfer the sections into `dataframes` and then `combine`, `merge` or `map` them.
The second to try row-by-row and iter sections as `lists` with `list comprehension`, but both did not produce the desired result.

###### EDIT

Thanks for the comments so far, glad to try and shed some light on this.

- In general, the values per section are ascending from left to right.
- The focus is on the `En` section, as this is the only section that is to be filled with values from the `Pn` section.
- `Pn` only serves as a gap filler - if `En` has a gap in a line, this should be filled by the corresponding value in `Pn`, if it is not already present in `En`.

Unfortunately, the data is real data and I can understand that it is difficult to understand due to the lack of my description, so I apologise.

Both sections have only a conditional real reference, but one could imagine `Pn` as packaging units and `En` as scale price quantities. In normal cases, the values `En` and `Pn` go together, but in some cases this analogous reference is missing and filling up is an attempt to standardise them.

Comment: are values always increasing in a row subgroup?

Comment: Why is `[2, E3]` filled from `[2,P4]` and not `[2,P3]`?

Comment: Or to put it another way, why is row 2 of `E` not `1, 10, 10, 160, ''`?

Comment: @Nick because of the first rule: "*Values that already exist in the En section must not be taken over from the Pn section.*", but the exact logic is still unclear and better examples would be appreciated

Comment: @mozway there's no value in `E3` or `E4` for that row, so my interpretation of that is that they should be copied from `P3` and `P4`. Unless OP means *specific* values i.e. `10` in this case. It's really not clear...

Comment: This really feels like an XY problem. Having some real data and an explanation to go with it would help immensely...

Comment: @Nick I agree, I've given it a quick try and rapidly got the feeling that critical information and background are missing. It's likely doable with several round of bfill/ffill and masks but might completely miss the real underlying logic

Comment: @mozway / Nick : thanks for your comments, added edit to my question that hopfully clarify the points you mentioned.

Comment: So when you say "Values that already exist in the En section" are you referring to specific values e.g. `10` or just filled locations?

Comment: In this case I am explicitly referring to the numerical value, if this already exists in En, it should not be transferred from Pn, even if the position, i.e. the cell in En, is empty. Without a shift of the value 160, which would be a nice to have, the row with index 2 would look like this.

|    | P1   | P2   | P3   | P4   | E1   |   E2 |   E3 | E4   | E5   |
|---:|:-----|:-----|:-----|:-----|:-----|-----:|-----:|:-----|:-----|
|  2 | 1    |      | 10   | 160  | 1    |   10 |   | 160  |      |

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your original DataFrame
df_original = pd.DataFrame({
    'P1':['','',1,''],
    'P2':[4,2,'',3],
    'P3':[48,20,10,''],
    'P4':['',320,160,264],
    'E1':['','',1,3],
    'E2':[4,2,10,264],
    'E3':[48,20,'',528],
    'E4':['','','',792],
    'E5':['','','','']
})

# Create a new DataFrame to store the results
df_result = df_original.copy()

# Define a function to fill the empty values in 'En' with 'Pn' based on conditions
def fill_with_pn(en_value, pn_value):
    if en_value == '':
        return pn_value
    else:
        return en_value

# Loop through columns P1 to P4 and apply the fill_with_pn function
for i in range(1, 5):
    df_result[f'E{i}'] = df_result.apply(lambda row: fill_with_pn(row[f'E{i}'], row[f'P{i}']), axis=1)

# Output the updated DataFrame
print(df_result)
```

Comment: This is not the correct output

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your original DataFrame
df_original = pd.DataFrame({
    'P1':['','',1,''],
    'P2':[4,2,'',3],
    'P3':[48,20,10,''],
    'P4':['',320,160,264],
    'E1':['','',1,3],
    'E2':[4,2,10,264],
    'E3':[48,20,'',528],
    'E4':['','','',792],
    'E5':['','','','']
})

#problem 1, n is not known automatically, so determine n
p_keys = []
e_keys = [] 

for key in df_original.keys():
    #find all the n's
    if key[0] == 'P':
        p_keys.append(int(key[1:]))     #use 1: for n > 9
    else:
        e_keys.append(int(key[1:]))

#select the largest value that are valid for both:
if p_keys <= e_keys:
    n_both = np.max(p_keys)
else:
    n_both = np.max(e_keys)         

print(df_original)      #original format

for i in np.arange(1,n_both+1,1):
    key_p = 'P' + str(i)
    key_e = 'E' + str(i)
    for j in range(len(df_original[key_p])): #assuming that column length for all columns is the same as is in your example
        #we don't want to do anything when there is already a value for E so:
        if df_original[key_e][j] != '':
            pass #means that the loop will go to the next j
        else:
            df_original.at[j, key_e] = df_original[key_p][j]
            
print(df_original)      #changed dataframe.
```

It is primarily using the basic python tools (for loops) to keep it simple and direct. Simultaneously, this means that if you have bigger datasets, there could be more efficient ways (I would not know how though). The comments explain what is happening, hope all is clear.

Comment: Not the correct output